# What happens when srcset is not supported?

Tags: html, srcset

I've been reading about [srcset](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/).

Unfortunately it does not have full compatibility with all browsers. What would happen with a browser that does not support it? Would all images be downloaded? Can I specify what image to use in this case?

Answer (score 5):

The `srcset` attribute is ignored in browsers that don't support it, so only the `src` attribute is used.